# itertools dice rolls: doubles roll twice

Tags: python, algorithm, python-itertools, python-collections

I'm trying to learn the Python library `itertools` and I thought a good test would be the simulation of dice rolls. It's easy to generate all possible rolls using `product` and counting the number of possible ways of doing so with the `collections` library. I'm trying to solve the problem that comes up in games like [Monopoly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopoly_%28game%29): when doubles are rolled, you roll again and your final total is the sum of the two rolls.

Below is my starting attempt at solving the problem: two Counters, one for doubles and the other for not doubles. I'm not sure if there is a good way to combine them or if the two Counters are even the best way of doing it.

**I'm looking for a slick way of solving (by enumeration) the dice roll problem with doubles using itertools and collections.**

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
from itertools import *

die_n = 2
max_num = 6

die = np.arange(1,max_num+1)
C0,C1  = Counter(), Counter()

for roll in product(die,repeat=die_n):
    if len(set(roll)) > 1: C0[sum(roll)] += 1
    else: C1[sum(roll)] += 1
```

Comment: Could you state the problem a little more formally?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Enumerate, using the libraries itertools and collections, the unnormalized probability distribution that arises when `n` dice numbered sequentially from `1` to `m` are rolled. The function to be counted is the sum of the `n` dice, except when all the dice match. If all the dice match on the first roll then number counted  is the sum of the first roll and a second roll. It does not matter if they match on the second roll. 

Sample rolls with two dice, numbered 1..6: `[3,4], [2,1], [[4,4], [6,2]]` giving totals of `[7,3,16]`.

Comment: You can consider solving this problem in Monte-Carlo style simulation.
If you think of this problem in a tree representation: start with root, roll once to the children with depth = 1, of which only child with doubles has subtree of deeper children of the same structure. It means those double-roll children points back to the root. Now you have a nice structure, and can do random renderings starting from root to estimate probability of event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving out `numpy` here for the sake of simplicity:

First, generate all rolls, be it single or double rolls:

```
from itertools import product
from collections import Counter

def enumerate_rolls(die_n=2, max_num=6):
    for roll in product(range(1, max_num + 1), repeat=die_n):
        if len(set(roll)) != 1:
            yield roll
        else:
            for second_roll in product(range(1, max_num + 1), repeat=die_n):
                yield roll + second_roll
```

Now a few tests:

```
print(len(list(enumerate_rolls()))) # 36 + 6 * 36 - 6 = 246
A = list(enumerate_rolls(5, 4))
print(len(A)) # 4 ** 5 + 4 * 4 ** 5 - 4 = 5116
print(A[1020:1030]) # some double rolls (of five dice each!) and some single rolls
```

and the result:

```
246
5116
[(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), (1, 1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 1, 1, 4), (1, 1, 1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1, 2, 3)]
```

To get the totals use the special `Counter` capabilities:

```
def total_counts(die_n=2, max_num=6):
    return Counter(map(sum, enumerate_rolls(die_n, max_num)))

print(total_counts())
print(total_counts(5, 4))
```

Results:

```
Counter({11: 18, 13: 18, 14: 18, 15: 18, 12: 17, 16: 17, 9: 16, 10: 16, 17: 16, 18: 14, 8: 13, 7: 12, 19: 12, 20: 9, 6: 8, 5: 6, 21: 6, 22: 4, 4: 3, 3: 2, 23: 2, 24: 1})
Counter({16: 205, 17: 205, 18: 205, 19: 205, 21: 205, 22: 205, 23: 205, 24: 205, 26: 205, 27: 205, 28: 205, 29: 205, 25: 204, 20: 203, 30: 203, 15: 202, 14: 200, 31: 200, 13: 190, 32: 190, 12: 170, 33: 170, 11: 140, 34: 140, 35: 102, 10: 101, 9: 65, 36: 65, 8: 35, 37: 35, 7: 15, 38: 15, 6: 5, 39: 5, 40: 1})
```

**Note:** At this point, there is no way of computing the probability for the totals. You have to know if it is a double roll or a total roll to weigh correctly.